Using Fedex Rate and Transit times api not getting delivery date
I’m using the FedEx Rate API (https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quotes) to get shipping rates, but I am not receiving the delivery date in the response. I have included the rateRequestControlParameters with returnTransitTimes set to true, but it doesn’t seem to affect the response.
{
  "accountNumber": {
    "value": 740561073
  },
  "requestedShipment": {
    "shipper": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": "16933",
        "countryCode": "US"
      }
    },
    "recipient": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": "02301",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "residential": true
      }
    },
    "pickupType": "DROPOFF_AT_FEDEX_LOCATION",
    "packagingType": "YOUR_PACKAGING",
    "shipDatestamp": "2024-08-19",
    "rateRequestType": [
      "ACCOUNT",
      "LIST"
    ],
    "requestedPackageLineItems": [
      {
        "weight": {
          "units": "LB",
          "value": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "rateRequestControlParameters": {
      "returnTransitTimes": true
    }
  }
}


I am not receiving any delivery date or transit time information in the response.

You are providing rateRequestControlParameters as a property of requestedShipment there, but the documentation clearly suggests that rateRequestControlParameters needs to be passed on the top level.

The issue is the shipDatestamp. You forgot the capital "S" for Stamp. The field name is shipDateStamp. It should work if you change that. Send also the rateRequestControlParameters on the top level.
